# d3-node bar graphs not displaying correctly

Tags: node.js, d3.js, ejs

I'm a novice at this. I am trying to build a simple dashboard for a web app and considered d3. I understand d3 dependency on HTML and hence I have installed d3-node and even did a mini-course through Udemy.

This is my code:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){

var chart_width = 800;
var chart_height = 400;
var bar_padding = 5;
const svg =  d3n.createSVG(chart_width, chart_height)

              .append('rect')
              .attr('width',25)
              .attr('height', 100);
  //bind data and create bars
  svg.selectAll('rect')
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     //generate the x coordinate dynamically
     .attr('x', function(d, i){
       return i * (chart_width / data.length); //
     })
     .attr('y',function(d){
       return chart_height - d * 5
     })
     .attr('width', chart_width / data.length - bar_padding)
     .attr('height', function(d){
       return d * 5;
     })
     .attr('fill', '#7ED26D');
  res.end(d3n.svgString())
```

I'm trying to get the concepts right, so this is a simple data set with 5 arrays. I don't get errors, but I only get one bar graph displaying. I suspect I need to return the other bars, but I have no idea how.

This is what my browser displays:

[image: Browser Display]

I have a lot more questions, and unfortunately, there is very little documentation regarding d3 and node specifically.

Comment: Done, I hope someone can help me get out of this maze... Last piece of the puzzle for my MVP App

Comment: Given that you are getting a blank page, I would guess you have JavaScript errors. However you have said that you are getting one bar in your SVG chart, and yet your image shows you have nothing displayed at all - could you clarify?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue ?